# How to map the first item in a collection with AutoMapper

Tags: .net, entity-framework, automapper

I have an object Foo gen'd with EF, it has a navigation property of Bar that is one to many, but should have been one to one. Anyways, when I query for a Foo I's also like to get the First and only item from the Bar collection and map these to a flattened out Biz Dto, how would I go about doing that?

```
        var result = (from c in ctx.Foo
                     where c.Bar.Any(cs => cs.LOGINNAME == username && cs.PASSWORD == password)
        select c).First();
```

Then in my AutoMapper Configuration I'd create a map that looked like????

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Biz>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CLIENTID))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bar.FirstOrDefault???))
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: You CreateMap calls look correct.  Are they not working for you?

Comment: @PatrickSteele Are you sure this is allowed? opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bar.FirstOrDefault???)

Comment: Obviously, you'd need to clean up the syntax, but yes, you are allowed to define a custom mapping on a per-field basis: opt.MapFrom(s => s.Bar.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: @PatrickSteele Can you answer this question?

Comment: @SteohenPlatten Did the s.Bar.FirstOrDefault() not work?

Comment: @PatrickSteele it did work, hence wanting you to get credit for the answer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault()` on the `Bar` collection when you map it:

```
opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bar.FirstOrDefault())
```

Answer (score -1):

Given:

```
public class Foo{
 public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Solution:

```
var result = from item in FooCollection
             select new { FirstBar = item.Bars.FirstOrDefault() };
```

where `FooCollection is IQueryable<Foo>`

Use FirstOrDefault so that there is no exception in case there are no related Bars

should do it I think...

HTH

Comment: Updated my question with an example.